# Login/registration button to open php file on same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, button

First of all sorry for my English. I'm working on a little website (I'm learning web design and PHP). As you can see in the page `index.php`, there are three buttons: login, registration (register) and guest. I've three scripts, one for login, one for register and one for guest access to site.

How can I show the script "login.php" or "register.php" or "guest.php", just under the buttons, when I click on the corresponding button?

Here are index.php and css files:

[Download](http://speedy.sh/Kbvmh/script.rar)

Comment: It is better to post the code on SO than to think people will download files from your website.

Comment: better yet, narrow down the issue and use a jsfiddle or a php fiddle

Comment: Never afraid to post code in SO. _No one_ is going to download files.

Comment: @SuperDJ i've tried to post both html and css codes, but the three css files are too long

Comment: @Antonio102 like Adelphia said narrow it down to the important code. Not all code is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jQuery http://www.jquery.com makes life soo much easier

```
$(document).on("click","#login-btn",function(){
    $("#div-where-to-load-stuff").load("url/to/login.php");
})
```

this is very bare bones. there are better ways to do it tho.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

You will have to either use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) or an [IFRAME](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) to load content asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

I really like to use the [jQuery Forms plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) (in case you are able to use jQuery). Otherwise you have to look into AJAX or iFrame.